# No available MessageBodyWriter for class X

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

I'am trying to send some mixed data from backend(spring) to backend (jersey)
data to be sent are mixed: objects, files.
I keep getting this error:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: No available MessageBodyWriter for class "class ClassContainsAllMixedData" and media type "multipart/mixed".

this is my part where i send request and wait for response:

```
 try(MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart()) {
        multiPart
            .bodyPart(new BodyPart(ClassContainsAllMixedData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))
            .bodyPart(
                    new BodyPart(file,
                            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE))
            .bodyPart(
                    new BodyPart(fileInfos,
                            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

        Response response = client.target(API_URI)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));
        System.out.println(response);
    }catch (ProcessingException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

I never get to display response because it fails at request.

these are the dependencies i use:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in dependancies version i fixed it by removing version tag and let pom get automatically the right version(2.7)

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```